# Polite email which gives update to a client

Tags: sentence, letter-writing

I have to give an general update to a person who is expecting a document from me. How can I politely put it? Is the following message good enough?

*Just to give an update. We are working on the document you requested. I can send the same by this Wednesday.*

Comment: "Just to give an update," would be better as a parenthesis; so use a comma followed by a small W. You mean by "same," the completed document, but as it stands you propose to send the document 'ready or not;' If you are sure say 'the completed document.'

Comment: Perhaps something like "Just a quick update" (to prepare them that it'll be very short).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

"We are working on the document you requested, and expect to send it to you by Wednesday."

I'm sure the recipient will figure out that this is an update, but if you want to get the word in there, you could put it in the subject box (assuming you are using email).